# Сonvert strategy version 2 to indicator version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Help me figure it out. I make an indicator from the strategy of the 2nd version in the 5th version.

```
//@version=2
//Heikin/Kaufman   by Marco

strategy("Heikin/Kaufman Strategy ",shorttitle="HAS/KAU",overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.EUR)
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="D")
test = input(0,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(20,"Slow EMA Period")

//Kaufman MA
Length = input(5, minval=1)
xPrice = input(hlc3)
xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
Fastend = input(2.5,step=.5)
Slowend = input(20)
nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA = nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))

//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, period, nAMA)
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, hlc3)

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],1)
sma = ema(ha_close,sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=black,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=red,linewidth=2,style=line)

//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma)

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong)
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

My indicator.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AnyDozer

//@version=5
indicator("Kaufman on HA", shorttitle ="KAU/HA", overlay = true)

res1 = input.timeframe('5', 'HA TF')
Length = input.int(5, 'Length KMA', minval=1)
xPrice = input.source(hlc3, 'Source KMA')
Fastend = input.float(2.5, 'Fast KMA', step=0.5)
Slowend = input(20, 'Slow KMA')
sloma = input(20, "Period EMA KMA")
cloma = input(1, "Period EMA HA")

//Kaufman MA
KMA(Length, xPrice, Fastend, Slowend) =>
    nAMA = 0.
    //Length = input(5, minval=1)
    //xPrice = input(hlc3)
    xvnoise = math.abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
    //Fastend = input(2.5,step=.5)
    //Slowend = input(20)
    nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
    nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
    nsignal = math.abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
    nnoise = math.sum(xvnoise, Length)
    nefratio = nnoise != 0 ? nsignal / nnoise : 0
    nsmooth = math.pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
    nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))
    nAMA

//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.ticker)

//Moving Average

mha_close = request.security(ha_t, res1, xPrice) //hlc3)
fma = ta.ema(mha_close[0], cloma) //mha_close //
plot(fma, title="MA", color=color.black, linewidth=2)

ha_close = request.security(ha_t, '', KMA(Length, xPrice, Fastend, Slowend)) //nAMA) 
sma = ta.ema(ha_close, sloma)
plot(sma, title="SMA", color=color.red, linewidth=2)

//Strategy
golong  = ta.crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort = ta.crossunder(fma,sma)

plotshape(golong, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(goshort, style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

[image]

The red charts `sma` are identical, and my black chart `fma` is one candle late. Why? Can this be fixed?

Comment: I think this is because `request.security` has lookahead_off by default

Comment: @AndreyD Thank you for your attention to my question. If both charts were lagging the same way, then I would understand you, but only the black chart is lagging, and the red ones are the same.

Comment: Good luck with debugging )

Answer (score 0):

I too tried to update this same strategy and having a problem that you show but didn't ask about.  Not sure why, but when I recreated it as an indicator I saw the plots off by one candle.  However, when I changed it back to being a strategy (as Marco did originally), that fixed the one candle problem for your "sma" variable (red line), which is the one you asked about.  But that isn't the biggest issue.

The bigger issue is why is the "fma" variable (black line) off by a full day/7 full candles?  Yours (and my recreation) are both off by a full day--calc is exactly the same but is plotted off by a full day.  Spent a few days trying to figure it out to no avail...

Comment: @AndreyD correctly wrote why the charts are lagging behind. This is due to the differences between version 2 and 5.  If you look closely, all the charts are shifted by one candle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it lagging by one candle but by a few.
Plus one the daily timeframe it's not lagging and gives the same results as v2 script.

I think it has to do with getting the data from the other timeframes which might work differently in v2 and v5.

Hope someone can solve this.

Comment: @AndreyD correctly wrote why the charts are lagging behind. This is due to the differences between version 2 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since the performance of the v2-script is too good to be true, I suspect that the script contains some kind of look-ahead-bias and uses information from the future. That's why it repaints.

The v5-script on the other hand behaves realistically, which is more useful.